# Using an array of URLs for importxml()?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get =importxml() working with an array of URLs. Arrayformula doesnt seem to do the Trick.

Has anyone of you done that before? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work - As annoying as it is - I have tried many many times to find some way to make it happen - Arrayformula just doesnt work with importxml, importdata or split.